# When report was downloaded from the Oracle ebs Excel report.While I am trying to open it was generating an error

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-ebs

The file format and extension of 'Accounts.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

It was generating this error while I am trying to open the downloaded excel report from the Oracle ebs

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

the Oracle EBS BI Publisher cannot create real xlsx Excel output files and generates and xml (xslt) format instead, which is given the extension xls to open automatically in Excel. Excel detects that the content does not match the expected binary xls format and shows the warning.
To avoid this problem, you can use third party products like [blitz report](https://www.enginatics.com/blitz-report/).